# Error when adding Google Play Services to phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services

Once I added the [Google Play SDK](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to my Phonegap project, I couldn't build the Project anymore via the command line. Here's the error I get:

[image]

Has anyone had this problem before? I didn't find anything helpful yet, so any hint is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `$cordova platform update android` Then run project again.